# python enum get by string value does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.6

I have the below enum

```
class Ranking(Enum):
    FIRST = 'First',
    SECOND = 'Second',
    THIRD = 'Third'
```

When I try `Ranking('First')` I get the following exception: `ValueError: 'First' is not a valid Ranking`

Is there any efficient way to get `Ranking.FIRST` from the string `'First'`?

Comment: using a dictionary?

Comment: Use `Ranking['First']`?

Comment: Ranking['First'] displays the same error

Comment: Did you try removing the commas?

Comment: Yep, that fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking C-style, where line breaks are meaningless and enum members need commas between them. In Python, line breaks matter, and those commas are actually creating tuples:

```
# How Python sees your code
class Ranking(Enum):
    FIRST = ('First',)
    SECOND = ('Second',)
    THIRD = 'Third'
```

Remove the commas.

Comment: oh interesting typo on a new feature.